# Trying to write java code that allows me to check status of POBox and change name of box owner

Tags: java

I am not sure what the issue is when I enter a box for the first choice a it returns

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not initialize box[0]. You only allocated the space of the array.

You should do something like:

```
box[0] = new PO();
```

Remember that 'new' the array doesn't mean you 'new' the object. The array you use is to store the references(pointers) of objects.

Also, to improve the evolvability, please use a dynamic array such as ArrayList. Since the size of array is fixed once you create it.

Answer (score 0):

```
PO[] box = new PO[nBoxes];
```

This line here is creating an array of references of class-type `PO`.
You need to allocate memory or create an instance using `new`.
For each reference in the array you must do this else the references point to `null`.
    `for(int i=0;i < nBoxes;i++) {
                    box[i] = new PO(); }`